# Include a nested value in the has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many

product.rb

```
class Product
 attr_accessible :name
 has_many :values
end
```

value.rb

```
class Value
 attr_accessible :value
 belongs_to :product
end
```

How include in the value instance ( `v = Value.find(3)` ) the name of product? 
Output value instance must be like this: `[v.product_name = product.name, v.name]`

Comment: What do you mean [v.product_name = product.name, v.name]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v.product.name
```

will get you the name of the product. Encapsulate that in a method of Value for better practice:

```
class Value
  def product_name
    product.name
  end
end
```

If your problem is that you want to do all that in one database call, you're looking at something like:

```
Value.select("values.*, products.name as product_name").joins(:product).find(3)
```

Honestly I don't think it's worth it for a search by id. If you are making a query that returns many results, I would eager load the associated products and go with what I suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method on your Value model like this.

```
def product_name
  "#{product.name}, #{name}"
end
```